# When is a definition via properties considered valid?

Tags: logic, meta-math

How one would define the validity of a definition of an object by its properties?

Little background: I'm trying to implement a kind of framework of mathematics in which the user is not restricted to any formal system, but can define anything at will just like in english but imposing logical constraints on the steps possible during a proof preventing mistakes. This obviously requires to prove that the definition is "valid".

Example: If we consider $G$ to be a group and $+$ its group operation, we can define $0\in G$ s.t. $\forall x\in G : x+0=0+x=x$, we can prove that two sets with such property are equal ($0_1 = 0_1 + 0_2=0_2$) so the definition is solid. Here equality is by definition $x=y :\iff (\forall z:(x\in z \iff y\in z)\land \forall w:(w\in x \iff w\in y)$, so basically in any formula of set theory we can freely replace $x$ with $y$ and vice versa. But what if we don't want to be restricted to set theory? Then what seems reasonable is to require for every definition a list of formulas(not necessarily of set theory) which constitutes the notion of "equality" and then proving that in these formulas they are indeed interchangeable. This issue does not arise when considering objects defined through expressions($3:=2+1$) as they are just directly replaceable short-hand notations.

Comment: "Not restricted to any formal system" makes this question very daunting to answer. It makes it sound like either you want an answer that work for _every possible_ formal system, or you want an answer that makes sense _without even having a formal system_ -- and both of these feel like an invitation to an unproductive goalpost-moving expedition. Would you be happy with an answer that assumes we're working within standard first-order logic?

Comment: thank you, I would appreciate it, it has to suffice until I manage to formalize my question (which, considering is a quest to formalize a system in which one can express any formalized system, might be a bust)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial answer that works in first-order logic is to have a definitional principle that says that if you can prove $\forall x_1, \ldots x_n\exists_{1}y\phi(y, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, then you can introduce a new $n$-place function symbol $f$, whose defining property is $\forall x_1, \ldots, x_n\phi(f(x_1, \ldots, x_n), x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. The special case when $n = 0$ lets you introduce new constant symbols. For a proof that this definitional principle is conservative (i.e., that it doesn't increase the logical strength of the theory), see Mendelson's *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* section 2.9.

Definitional principles along these lines are implemented in interactive proof systems such as the various members of the [HOL family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOL_(proof_assistant)). The definitional principles are formulated as inference rules (they have one or more antecedent theorems) that make theory extensions (the signature of the language is extended in the theorem that is the succedent of the rule).

Comment: By the way, your "definitional principle" is simply "full abbreviation power" that I mentioned in my answer. And you don't just want function symbols but also predicate symbols so that you can do restricted quantification.

Comment: I have never encountered the term "full abbreviation power" in a reasonably long acquaintance with the relevant literature. The only google hits I get for it are quotations from you. So I think the OP will find it more helpful to have an answer that uses standard terminology. Predicate symbols are trivial to deal with: if $\phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is any formula whatsoever with only the listed free variables, then it is conservative to introduce a new $n$-place predicate $P$ whose defining property is $\forall x_1, \ldots x_n(P(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \Leftrightarrow \phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n))$.

Comment: Actually I didn't invent that term. It came from FOM posts. Yes predicates are simple but functions are not hard either. If you can prove $\exists! y\ ( φ(x_{1..k},y) )$ then it is conservative to introduce a new function symbol $f$ with the axiom $\forall x_{1..k},y\ ( φ(x_{1..k},y) \leftrightarrow f(x_{1..k}) = y )$. This is the same way that we define whether functions are representable (or can be captured) by a formula, because there is a (computable) translation from one to the other that preserves provability.

Comment: By the way, the book "A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Wolfgang Rautenberg uses the term "definitorial extension of $T$" for the **extension** of $T$ by adding new predicate symbols or function symbols defined by a formula. It also says that in less formalized theories the ability to introduce such new symbols can be regarded as a mechanism for "abbreviation of explicit definitions". But if you have a reference that describes formal systems which can internally create new abbreviations or temporarily move to definitorial extensions, tell me and I'll switch terminology.

Answer (score 0):

As Henning has already said, you need to decide on an underlying logical system, because there are incompatible logical systems and you cannot prove anything without using any logic. Suppose you pick (classical) first-order logic. Then once you implement the deductive system, you basically can use it for any finitely axiomatized first-order theory; to verify $T \vdash P$ where $T$ has axioms $X$, you simply prove $\bigwedge_{A \in X} A \to P$.

However, if you want to be able to handle any recursively axiomatizable first-order theory, you clearly need something more. One way would be to have meta rules for assuming schemas. Also, presumably you want to be able to define new constants, functions and predicates, so you would probably want to add full abbreviation power. You might want to have namespaces so that you can restrict added stuff to only where they are needed.

It would be a good idea to study how programming languages are designed, since a lot of issues for formal systems have already been studied and solved by programming language designers long ago.

Comment: And equality is **not** defined like in your question. It's weaker than the standard first-order equality. There is no point in changing it, because any alternative notion of equality can be axiomatized as a new binary predicate; why should we disturb the standard intuitive equality?

Comment: The critique of the question in your comment is not justified. It is very common to develop set theory as a first order theory in a language with membership as its only predicate symbol and to define equality by extensionality as the OP did. E.g., see the development of axiomatic set theory in Mendelson's  *Introduction to Mathematical Logic*.

Comment: @RobArthan: I know that but the asker explicitly asked for a general framework not restricted to set theory, and so it makes no sense to even want to have any ingrained notion of objects as sets!

Comment: @RobArthan: Also, it just occurred to me that for any theory over first-order logic without equality, adding the equality symbol and the inference rules for equality is in fact conservative! This shows that we can indeed use a new binary predicate for any other desired notion of equality, instead of changing the standard equality rules, which are not reliant on set-theoretic foundations.

Answer (score -2):

If we go into the mathematical realm a "thing which does not exist" is just a set of properties which cannot be satisfied.